# MySQL - fill missing dates

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I have this query and I want to fill missing dates with some values (zero for example...)

```
SELECT date, SUM(val1) as sum_val  
FROM table1  
WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-03-04' AND '2016-03-10'  
GROUP BY date
```

Here is result:

```
|--------------------------  
|date, sum_val  
|--------------------------  
|2016-03-04, 21568  
|--------------------------  
|2016-03-05, 14789  
|--------------------------  
|2016-03-08, 20568  
|--------------------------  
|2016-03-10, 5841  
|--------------------------
```

How can I populate missing dates with zero values? Does anyone has an idea?

I need this data for **chart** preview.

Comment: you need to use an additional table with calendar or an procedure to make temporary table with dates range

Comment: there is no some other way to do that?

Comment: just loop for one month and make condition if its match with ur exist date then no need to insert data and rather then add with 0.

Comment: You can select each date manualy, other then that with pure sql - no

Comment: @Heril Muratovic in mysql - no. But you can do this in php

Comment: you need only sql query or php code also acceptable for insert zero?

Comment: @ Ruchish Parikh I try to find the best way to do that... no matter if I use mysql or php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can generate a series of N integers in MySQL using:

```
    select (@i:=@i+1)-1 as `myval` from someTable,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub limit N
```

**Note that the table that you join on (someTable) must have at least N rows.**  The -1 above is to make it base-zero... remove it and you'll get 1,2,3 for N=3.

You can feed those integers into the DATE_ADD function to turn it into a series of dates.  To make it easier to follow, let's use some user variables for the dates.

```
SET @date_min = '2016-03-04';
SET @date_max = '2016-03-10';

select DATE_ADD(@date_min, INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as `date`
from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub
where DATE_ADD(@date_min,INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN @date_min AND @date_max
```

That will return rows for those days and every day between them.  Now it's just a matter of joining against your table... I haven't tried it since I don't have your db structure, but something like the following should work:

```
SET @date_min = '2016-03-04';
SET @date_max = '2016-03-10';

SELECT
   date_generator.date,
   ifnull(SUM(val1),0) as sum_val
from (
   select DATE_ADD(@date_min, INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as `date`
   from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub 
   where DATE_ADD(@date_min,INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN @date_min AND @date_max
) date_generator
left join table1 on table1.date = date_generator.date
GROUP BY date;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this PHP loop:

```
$date1 = Your_first_date_value;
$date2 = Your_limit_date;
for ($d1 = $date1; d1<=$date2; strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($d1))) {
    //Fill in values
}
```

`strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date1))` will increment by 1 day the current value of `$date1` until it is equal to `$date2`.

When a date does not have a value it will be zero, and if the date exist, it will get the sum according to MySQL result.

Comment: @downvoter why ????? It is working for me in my project

Comment: I will try this...

Comment: should $date1 and $date2 be strtotime values?

Comment: Have you got some errors ? What is the output ? STRTOTIME: `The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code its similar to your query and surely work and helful to you.

```
$query = "SELECT date, SUM(val1) as sum_val  
FROM table1  
WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-03-04' AND '2016-03-10'  
GROUP BY date";
$result = mysql_db_query($db,$query);
$dateArray = Array();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $dateArray[] = strtotime($row['date']);
}


$from = "1-4-2016";
$to = "30-4-2016";
$datediff = strtotime($from) - strtotime($to);
$days = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
for ($d1 = 1; $d1<$days; $d1++) {
    $cdate = strtotime("+".$d1." day", strtotime($from));
    if(!in_array($cdate, $dateArray))
    {
        // Insert record with zero
    }
}
```

Comment: but why for 30 days?

Comment: its for one month and if you want to make it dynamic then we need to find total days between from and to dates and just pass it in $d1<$totalDays. @HerilMuratovic

Comment: yeah, I need it to be dynamic.

Comment: Please check edited answer it works surely for you. @HerilMuratovic

Comment: Please provide your feedback. @HerilMuratovic

Comment: give me some time... I will check your answer if it works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108181/discussion-between-ruchish-parikh-and-heril-muratovic).