# Building report with date gaps

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make a report with sales by seller in a certain range of dates.
The problem I have is that the report should also pick up sellers who have not made any sales on that day.

Vendors (table)

```
id | name
----------
 1 | John
 2 | Tom
```

Sales (table)

```
id | vendor_id |    date        | status | price
------------------------------------------------
 1 |        1  |    2019-01-01  |    0   | 100
 2 |        1  |    2019-01-01  |    0   | 100 
 3 |        2  |    2019-01-01  |    0   | 100
 4 |        2  |    2019-01-02  |    0   | 100
```

Desired Report: Total sales between **2019-01-01** and **2019-01-04**

```
date        |vendor| total
--------------------------
2019-01-01  | John | 200
2019-01-01  | Tom  | 100
2019-01-02  | John | 0
2019-01-02  | Tom  | 100
2019-01-03  | John | 0
2019-01-03  | Tom  | 0
2019-01-04  | John | 0
2019-01-04  | Tom  | 0
```

To generate the sequence of days I'm using the date generator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402030/mysql-fill-missing-dates/38775614#38775614)

And when I cross (left join) the dates generated with the `sales` I get the following:

```
SELECT date_generator.daily_date, vendors.name, sales.price
        FROM ( 
            SELECT DATE_ADD(@startDate, INTERVAL (@i:=@i + 1) - 1 DAY) AS daily_date   
            FROM information_schema.columns, (SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub   
            WHERE DATE_ADD(@startDate, INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate 
        ) date_generator 
        LEFT JOIN sales ON DATE(sales.date) = DATE(date_generator.daily_date)
        LEFT JOIN vendors ON vendors.id = sales.vendor_id
ORDER BY date_generator.daily_date

date        |vendor| price
--------------------------
2019-01-01  | John | 100
2019-01-01  | John | 100
2019-01-01  | Tom  | 100
2019-01-02  | Tom  | 100
2019-01-03  | null | null
2019-01-04  | null | null
```

Can you give me some trick to get the grouping of vendor and date?

Comment: Your approach seems wrong. Firstly, you never aggregate and sum() so how do you expect '200'? Secondly while the date generator with the sub-query is smart, it won't satisfy your needs because you'll only get as many rows per date (day) as many vendors have sales for that date and using left join you'll get NULL's for dates when no vendor had sales. I suggest you you simplify the query (besides adding grouping and aggregation) something like this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2TQJKn2SqZwEEqxcoqqc9M/1 and transfer the date interval logic to the application layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some days have no sales, you will have a `NULL` `sales.vendor.id` value, so nothing to `JOIN` to `vendors`. To make sure you get all the vendors on all the dates, you need to do a `CROSS JOIN` from `date_generator` to `vendors`, and then `LEFT JOIN` to sales. Then you need to take the `SUM` of `sales.price` and `GROUP BY` the date and the vendor to get your desired output:

```
SELECT date_generator.daily_date, vendors.name, SUM(sales.price)
        FROM ( 
            SELECT DATE_ADD(@startDate, INTERVAL (@i:=@i + 1) - 1 DAY) AS daily_date   
            FROM information_schema.columns, (SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub   
            WHERE DATE_ADD(@startDate, INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate 
        ) date_generator 
        CROSS JOIN vendors
        LEFT JOIN sales ON DATE(sales.date) = DATE(date_generator.daily_date) AND vendors.id = sales.vendor_id
GROUP BY date_generator.daily_date, vendors.name
```

Comment: Really nice answer, I was freaking out. Thank you Nick!